# Proof in the topic of solution of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$O, A, B, C$ are the four points on straight line such that the distances of $A, B, C$ from $O$ are the roots of equation $ax^3+3bx^2+3cx+d=0$. If $B$ is the middle point of $AC$, show that $a^2d-3abc+2b^3=0$.

**EDIT:**
**I solved it using Vieta's formula. But I am looking for an alternative solution**

On $OABC$ straight line, I took $OA=q, AB=p \ and \ BC=p$. 
Then the roots are $q, (p+q), (2p+q)$

$Σα = (\dfrac {-3b}{a})$ 
$Σαß = (\dfrac {3c}{a})$ 
$∏α = (\dfrac {-d}{a})$

$Σα= 3(p+q) = (\dfrac {-3b}{a}) \Rightarrow (p+q)= (\dfrac {-b}{a})$

$Σαß = q(p+q)+q(2p+q)+(p+q)(2p+q)=(\dfrac {3c}{a})$ 
$\Rightarrow 2(p+q)^2+q(q+2p)=(\dfrac {3c}{a})$ 
$\Rightarrow q(p+\overline{p+q})=\dfrac {3ac-2b^2}{a^2}$ 
$\Rightarrow q(p-\dfrac{b}{a})=\dfrac {3ac-2b^2}{a^2}$----(1)

$∏α = q(p+q)(2p+q)= (\dfrac {-d}{a})$ 
$\Rightarrow q(\dfrac {-b}{a})(p-\dfrac {b}{a})=\dfrac {-d}{a}$ 
$\Rightarrow q(p-\dfrac {b}{a})=\dfrac {d}{b}$------(2)

Equating (1) & (2)

$\dfrac {3ac-2b^2}{a^2}=\dfrac {d}{b}$
Solving which we get, 
$a^2d-3abc+2b^3=0$

**I am looking for alternative solutions.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are more likely to get a response if you show that you've made an effort

Comment: Please check the edit.